# How does one get the drives mapped to a SQL instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql, powershell

How do I obtain a list of all of the drives associated with or being used by a SQL Server instance (2005 & up)? The list should include fixed hard drives and mount points. I've been toying with sp_OAGetProperty but that one doesn't give what I want.

My next stop/attempt would be to do this in Powershell if it's not possible via T-SQL.

Comment: See: [CLR stored procedure to get disk space information](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2007/12/18/60435.aspx)

Comment: Do you want all the drives that the instance can SEE or what it's using?

Comment: More on the latter. The data, tempdb and log drives are easy enough to get, the backup drive however is the harder one to get for me.

Answer (score 3):

This lists all the attached drives:

```
EXEC master..xp_fixeddrives
```

Shark's query is good and lists the drives that the SQL Server has in use from a SQL Server system perspective.

```
select distinct LEFT(physical_name, 2)
from sys.master_files -- Sharky's query
```

The second query as mentioned, will not show you all the drives that are being used by SQL Server if stored procedures are referencing specific physical drives that the SQL Server instance isn't using explicitly.  To determine that, you may want to search the code for references to the drives found in the list produced by the first sproc call.

In my case, the second query shows only drive D: but I have code in stored procedures that reference drive F for files that get bulk inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what will get you what you want:

```
select distinct LEFT(physical_name, 2)
from sys.master_files
```

What that does is gets the summary drives (i.e. `C:`) used by all databases in your given instance.

Comment: It's not clear if he wants to know all the drives in use or all the drives that **can** be used.  This will only show drives that have a DB attached currently.

Comment: @JNK "obtain all of the drives associated or being used" I took that to mean all the drives being used.  I maybe mistaken, though.

Comment: `Associated` is what makes me think he wants all drives that the instance can access.

Comment: @JNK hmm... good point.  Some clarification from the OP will be much needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not on a cluster, any drive on the machine can be used for your database files.  If you are on a cluster, give sys.dm_io_cluster_shared_drives a look.

Comment: This was especially helpful for MS-configured clusters. Thanks!